# TP-LINK tl-wn821n v4.2 dongle wi-fi hotspot issue

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am creating hotspot using tl-wn821n dongle on ubuntu 14.04. But after creating hotspot, it gets disconnected automatically. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the kernel version of ubuntu above 4.2, then ubuntu has inbuilt support for TP-LINK tl-wn821n usb adapter.